# How to bind wooden pieces together, but detachable

Tags: wood, design

I want to bind these pieces together, but **not a permanent one**. I want to be able to like pop one out whenever I want. Kinda like a Lego bond.

I thought of putting magnets on them but couldn't find a suitable one and I just can't think of any other nice solution. Any idea?

- The Idea here is to cover part of my wall with this
- I want to be able to change it over time and give it a new look
- They are only needed to be attached to each other like a brick wall in the shape you see in the picture (one going over the half of two others)
- It's necessary to have any extra metal or stuff used other than these pieces to be out of sight
- I don't want to be forced to take it all apart to change the shape

[image]

Comment: How many different connection points on each block?

Comment: Must the connection be out of sight?  Is this horizontal as in your picture, or does it get turned vertical to become a wall?  Do you really need the ability to pop out a single piece, or are you okay with taking it apart and reassembling?

Comment: @AstPace I added more info

Comment: @isherwood, I just want them to hold in place and not fall, so as much as necessary. maybe one on each side?

Answer (score 9):

- You could try [Lincoln Log™](http://www.knex.com/products/lincoln-logs/) style

  - A nice DIY write up at [Lumberjocks](http://lumberjocks.com/SPalm/blog/42826)
  - At least they are still made of wood.
- You could use round magnets like those found [here](https://wondertrail.com/hobby-supplies-en/magnets/macnsn0657-1-4-x-1-16-magnets-dics-by-magcraft.html).

  - You'd want to make the hole with a Forstner bit, and hold them in with epoxy. I'd suggest keeping the magnets away from each other until the epoxy has completely set to ensure they don't pull each other out of their holes.

[image: https://wondertrail.com/images/detailed/28/MACNSN0657.jpg]

- You could try [Tinker Toy™](http://www.knex.com/products/tinkertoy/) style and make or buy the small connecting dowels.

  - On a sad note, it seems that Tinker Toys are now made out of plastic instead of wood. I'd vote for this option simply for nostalgia's sake.

Comment: You can get similar magnets with a countersunk hole. Using epoxy takes some getting right because the magnets are so strong. I would very slightly recess the magnets so they don't touch the mounting (which could be another magnet or more simply a steel sheet).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "magnet with a countersunk hole". My suggestion was to drill the hole in the wood to put the magnet in. I'm certain you're not suggesting a hole in the magnet, so I'm confused...

Comment: I mean a hole in the magnet (manufactured like that). First Google hit for "rare earth magnet screw hole": http://www.first4magnets.com/countersunk-magnets-c41 (not bought from these people). The screw mounted magnets are great.

Comment: ah, gotcha! Yes, I see where screwing then in might be quite a but easier!

Comment: With magnets I would suggest to have them flush with the surface of the wood. This way, when the pieces are attached to the wall the magnets touch the other magnet/steel plate on the wall. Otherwise the fastening mechanism (be it glue or a screw) will be under constant pulling force from the magnet trying to come closer to the wall.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to use wide horizontal velcro strips on the back of each block and mate them with vertical velcro straps.  You can easily change the arrangement .  Only a few key blocks will need to have picture hangers to attach to the wall.

Comment: Or firmly attach one half of the velcro to the wall with glue/nails/screws.

Comment: Or put the Velcro on a backer board that is hung on the wall.